# How to check if a String is not empty in php, to prevent undefined function calls?

Tags: php, arrays, string

So basically, I have a String that is located in a two dimensional Array like this.

```
$array[$i][$k];
```

I applied some includes() functions on those strings to change it's color whenever it contains "SA" but not "SAP" or "Schulaufgabe" OR "Unterrichtsende"

```
if ($array[$i][$k].includes("SA") && !$array[$i][$k].includes("SAP") || 
$array[$i][$k].includes("Schulaufgabe") || $array[$i][$k].includes("Unterrichtsende"))
```

I tried many options to prevent this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function includes() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php:101 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 101

For example with this method.

```
if (strlen($array[$i][$k]) != 0)
```

None of them did work. Are there any other options to get rid of this error?

Comment: You can use `if (!empty($array[$i][$k]))`

Comment: You don't call functions with `.` in PHP. That's JavaScript syntax for calling methods.

Comment: If you want to search for a substring in PHP, use `strpos()`.

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: If you want to search for multiple strings, use a regexp. `if (preg_match('/SA(?!P)| Schulaufgabe|Unterrichtsende/'))`

Comment: The error has nothing to do with checking for an empty string. There's simply no function called `includes()` in PHP. You're mixing up languages.

Comment: the preg_match one solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/SA(?!P)|Schulaufgabe|Unterrichtsende/',$array[$i][$k])) {
    echo "<td style='color: red'>" . $array[$i][$k];          
}
```

The Answer was in the method .includes() which just partly worked, I do not recommend using it! Even though I found it somewhere in the phpManual